# How to check if link still the same?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to check if this link still valid or not`https://www.udemy.com/course/artificial-intelligence-in-digital-marketing/?couponCode=DIGITALMARKETING`, as once this coupon expires it would turn me to the original course page `https://www.udemy.com/course/artificial-intelligence-in-digital-marketing/`, I have used selenium to do this, but it's kinda slow and Udemy block me after two pages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
i= "https://www.udemy.com/course/artificial-intelligence-in-digital-marketing/?couponCode=DIGITALMARKETING"
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(i)
time.sleep(1)
currentUrl= driver.current_url
if i== currentUrl:
    print("true")
```

Does anyone have an idea for a fester way to do that? I have tried using urllib3 and requests, but neither of them worked. I tried to parse it with Beautiful Soup also hoping to find something in the code but I couldn't find any because the web site is dynamic.

Comment: Fetch the page using `requests`, and see if the response is a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `requests` library.  You can check the response url, or check the history attribute to see if it was redirected during the route.

For example:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"

In [3]: res = requests.get(url)

In [4]: res.url == url
Out[4]: False

In [5]: res.url
Out[5]: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

In [6]: res.history
Out[6]: [<Response [301]>]
```

In the example above you can see that the request was redirected from `https://www.stackoverflow.com` to `https://stackoverflow.com`

Here is a one line function using the same strategy.

```
import requests

def url_is_not_redirected(url):
    return requests.get(url).url == url
```

The speed of course will vary based on network connection but it is guaranteed to be faster than using selenium.

Comment: If the two urls are the same, then it _wasn't_ redirected, surely?

Comment: @JohnGordon  I don't know if that is always the case but it is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Your function returns true if the two urls are the same, which seems counter to its name.

Comment: @JohnGordon Excellent point. That was not intentional.  Thanks